# miss part of html by getting html by requests in python

Tags: python, html

When I view the page source in my browser, the html I am after appears there. However, when I make a requests using python requests the html doesn't appear.

The url I'm trying to scrape is http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20161212, and the specific html I am after in the page is:

[image]

I'd like to get the tag . So far I've tried:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20161212')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
b= soup.find(name = 'section',class_ = 'col-b')
print(b)
```

out:

## NBA Scoreboard

Auto Update: On

### Sponsored Headlines

as we can see,much part of tag  was missed in the print,like tag